# AWS KCL MultiLanguageDaemon - override Dynamo table name used for checkpointing

Tags: c#, .net-core, amazon-kinesis

According to the following [article](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/kinesis-kcl-apps-dynamodb-table) it's possible to override the the DynamoDB table used for checkpointing when using the KCL directly.

> Here's an example of how to set up a table name on KCL version 1.x:
>
> ```
> KinesisClientLibConfiguration kinesisClientLibConfiguration =  new KinesisClientLibConfiguration(...).withTableName(<table_name>);// KCL 1.x
> ```
>
> You can also manually set up a table name on KCL version 2.x:
>
> ```
> ConfigsBuilder configsBuilder = new ConfigsBuilder(...).tableName(<table_name>); // KCL 2.x
> ```

I'm wondering is there's anyway to do so via the `kcl.properties` file when using the AWS KCL MultiLanguageDaemon in .NET?

I've looked through the Java source of the [AWS KCL](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/tree/master) and I'm pretty sure the answer is no.  However, my Java skillset is rusty and out of date, so I thought it was worth asking the question.